# Pyomo time constraint to balance demand with production and storage

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am currently trying to develop an optimization model but I am stuck at one of the constraints. I have a model with demand input per hour for a whole year. To satisfy demand (D(t)), each time period, I want to produce a specific amount of products (P(t)) or use products which have been stored from previous time periods (S(t-1)). I want to write a constraint which states that the demand in one time period must be equal to or smaller than the production in the time period + the storage stock in that time period. Something similiar to:

D(t) <= P(t) + S(t-1)

The demand per time period is 'stored' in a dataframe:

```
demand = pd.read_csv('hub_1h.csv', usecols = ['Peak Capacity'], sep = ';')
demand.index = pd.date_range(start = '2024-1', freq = '1H', periods = 8784)
```

I have created two dataframes for both the production and storage level at each time period:

```
mh2 = pd.DataFrame(range(0, 8784))
mh2.index = pd.date_range(start = '2024-1', freq = '1H', periods = 8784)
model.MH2 = pyo.Var(mh2, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals)  
soch2 = pd.DataFrame(range(0, 8784))
soch2.index = pd.date_range(start = '2024-1', freq = '1H', periods = 8784)
model.SoCH2 = pyo.Var(soch2, within = pyo.NonNegativeReals)
```

To balance overall demand over the entire year with production and storage, I have the working constraint:

```
model.c1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = (sum(model.MH2[i] for i in mh2) * (39.4 / 1000)) + (sum(model.SoCH2[i] for i in soch2) * (39.4 / 1000)) == (sum(demand['Peak Capacity'])))
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to develop a constraint to ensure that demand in each time period is equal to or lesser than production and storage in that time period. I have tried the following code:

```
model.c2 = pyo.Constraint(expr = (demand['Peak Capacity'] ) <=  (((model.MH2[i] for i in mh2) * (39.4 / 1000))) + ((model.SoCH2[j] for j in soch2) * (39.4 / 1000)))
```

With this code I, however, get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'generator' and 'float'. I do not know how to fix this. If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to help you.  Here is my suggestion:  Set aside pandas and this huge problem (8000+ time steps) and develop from scratch a tiny model with 5 time steps that has some capacitance (storage), production, and a varying demand signal such that the storage would be expected to be taxed and replenished under normal ops.  Try to get that working, which will help you learn the fundamentals of this model.  How many variables are needed?  How to balance what happens w/ storage?  re-post a new question with that model if you are stuck and you'll get better help.